# Need excel formula to sort out specific ranges of dates from dataset

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need a formula that will sort out records in a data set that are both at night and between December 1 and March 31.  The time and date are in one cell, formatted like this example "2005-03-24 18:59:19"

I think the night-time range could be something like the hours between 20:00 and 0400.

The time date column is formatted as a custom format, as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

I tried reasra's suggestion and I think it worked, see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you wanted to extract fractions of hours, it would get more complicated than just `HOUR`.  Just remember that Excel stores dates in the number of days since epoch.  So, the fractions of the number will give you the fractions of the day.  In which case, you could multiply by 24 to get hours with `MOD(A1,1)*24`.  So you're answer would look something like this:

```
=IF(OR(MOD(A1,1)*24<4.5,MOD(A1,1)*24>19.5),TRUE,FALSE)
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

When I paste your example "2005-03-24 18:59:19", Excel recognizes it as a DateTime.  If this is true for you too, use the following formula to "sort out records"

```
=IF(OR(HOUR(A1)<4,HOUR(A1)>20),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Since you didn't mention what you want to do with them, I left `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  If your string is not recognized as a time, please clarify by updating your question.

Comment: Thanks, appears to work.  How would I change the time limit to say 4:30 instead of 4:00?

Comment: @MalcolmG Updated answer.

Comment: Great, that worked too, thanks.  That works for the time question.  Can you also solve the month of the year issue? ie, have it display true if the date is within December 1 to March 31?

Comment: OK, here's the formula for getting the "day of year" `=DAYS(A1,DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0))`.  Compare that to the dates and use the same operations as with the time.  And next time, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for poor question phrasing.  I gave all my records a day of year number with your last formula.  But now, how do I mark true all the days <90 and >335?  Basic I know, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably something like `IF(AND(DAYS(A1,DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0))<90,DAYS(A1,DATE(YEAR(A1),1,0))>335))`.  I'm not able to get to Excel right now.